Customize Action Expired message for each method in keycloak
I am using the keycloak forgot password and user actions functionalities. When using these functionality keycloak is sending a mail to users. When the mail is expired keycloak is commonly showing the message Action expired..
I was able to change this message by editing \themes\mytheme\login\messages\messages_en.properties file by modify the expiredActionMessage value.
expiredActionMessage=Action expired.

But is there anyway i can modify the action expired message specific to what action i have done?
e.g., for forgot password action message will be something like Action expired. trigger forgot password again. and for user actions message something like Action expired. Ask your manager to retrigger user activation.
